# Connect to MongoDB Change Streams with TypeORM / NestJS

Tags: angular, mongodb, nestjs

Do you know any idea of connecting to [MongoDB Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) using NestJS + TypeORM? An example is really appreciated.

I'm using NestJS for my backend and Angular for my frontend. I'm able to connect to MongoDB using `typeorm/MongoRepository` from NestJS. I wanna update "in real time" the changes in data on MongoDB.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but if it's still relevant, maybe you can refer to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1740). Cheers!